# Change from all posts to specific categories post on main page?

Tags: posts, theme-development, categories, query-posts

How do I change my index.php to display only the desired categories posts in the main page ?

I tought that changing this would workout but instead it just print nothing:

```
            query_posts( array(
            'post_type' => array(
                        'post',
                        $include_reviews,
                        $include_screenshots,
                        $include_videos
                    ),
                    'paged' => $paged )
                );
```

Change from `'post',` to `'cat=10',` not very sure how to do this.

This is my index.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    $slider_number = get_option('lp_slides_number');
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'slider', 'showposts' => $slider_number );
    $slider_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($slider_loop->have_posts()) : ?>
    <!-- BEGIN SLIDER -->
    <div class="slider">

        <div class="sliderContent">

        <?php while ( $slider_loop->have_posts() ) : $slider_loop->the_post(); $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), false, '' ); ?>
            <div class="featured-item" style="background:<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature_bg', true); ?> url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?>) no-repeat center; height:280px;">

                <div class="featured-inner">

                    <div class="featured-inner">

                        <div class="featured-arrows"></div>
                        <h1><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature_url', true); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Link Permanente: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <p class="featured-meta">Por <?php the_author(); ?>, <?php the_time( get_option('date_format') ); ?></p>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </div>

        <div class="top-overlay"></div>
        <div class="bottom-overlay"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- END SLIDER -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- BEGIN MAIN WRAPPER -->
    <div id="main-wrapper">

        <!-- BEGIN MAIN -->
        <div id="main">

            <!-- BEGIN NEWS WRAPPER -->
            <div id="news-wrapper">

                <h3 class="section-title">Last News</h3>

                <!-- BEGIN NEWS ITEMS -->
                <?php

                if(get_option('lp_include_reviews') == "true") { $include_reviews = "'reviews',"; }
                if(get_option('lp_include_videos') == "true") { $include_videos = "'videos',"; }
                if(get_option('lp_include_screenshots') == "true") { $include_screenshots = "'screenshots',"; }

                query_posts( array(
                'post_type' => array(
                            'post',
                            $include_reviews,
                            $include_screenshots,
                            $include_videos
                        ),
                        'paged' => $paged )
                    );
                ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php

                    if ( get_post_type() == 'reviews' ) : ?>

                        <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-reviews-frontpage.php' ); ?>

                    <?php elseif ( get_post_type() == 'videos' ) : ?>

                        <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-videos-frontpage.php' ); ?>

                    <?php elseif ( get_post_type() == 'screenshots' ) : ?>

                        <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-screenshots-frontpage.php' ); ?>

                    <?php else: ?>

                        <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-posts.php' ); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php kriesi_pagination(); ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- END NEWS ITEMS -->

            </div>
            <!-- END NEWS WRAPPER -->

        </div>
        <!-- END MAIN -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, change:

```
 query_posts( array(
                'post_type' => array(
                            'post',
                            $include_reviews,
                            $include_screenshots,
                            $include_videos
                        ),
                        'paged' => $paged )
                    );
```

to:

```
 query_posts( array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( $include_reviews,
                                $include_screenshots,
                                $include_videos )
            )),
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'post')
);
```

Comment: it is not about the `$include_...`, they work just fine it is about not printing all posts in the blog but just posts in a selected category.

Comment: what???? i guess i don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Hi @:Prix Try this Plugin: [Select Category to Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/select-category-to-post/).It'll work:)Here You Select Category as your wish and also post that category like posts.

Comment: How would I use it to display on the index.php only the pre-defined categories I want (no user interaction) the plugin page does not show any information on the usage ?